# Sidecar Container not printing logs

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, docker-volume

I am newbie in dealing with sidecar container. What i am trying to do this, my main container is generating logs, and i want my sidecar to read that logs. But when i do try to read logs using below command

```
kubectl logs -f currency-exchange -c sidecar-container
```

it says

```
cat: can't open '/var/log/in28min/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.11- 
SNAPSHOT/access.log': No such file or directory
```

Basically its not creating the file access.log inside the directory, entire folder structure is created.

Below is my yaml file.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: currency-exchange
  labels:
    app: currency-exchange
spec:
  containers:
    - name: main-application
      image: in28min/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.11-SNAPSHOT
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /var/log/in28min/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.11-SNAPSHOT
    - name: sidecar-container
      image: busybox
      command: ["sh","-c","while true; do cat /var/log/in28min/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.11-SNAPSHOT/access.log; sleep 30; done"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /var/log/in28min/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.11-SNAPSHOT
  volumes:
    - name: shared-logs
      emptyDir: {}

---

# Service Configuration
# --------------------
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: currency-exchange
  name: currency-exchange

spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: currency-exchange
  type: LoadBalancer
```

In my main container its an SpringBoot Microserservice, where i am writing my logs.

```java
package com.in28minutes.microservices.currencyexchangeservice;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class CurrencyExchangeController {
    
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CurrencyExchangeController.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private CurrencyExchangeRepository repository;
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    
    @GetMapping("/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}")
    public CurrencyExchange retrieveExchangeValue(
            @PathVariable String from,
            @PathVariable String to) {
        
        logger.info("retrieveExchangeValue called with {} to {}", from, to);
        
        CurrencyExchange currencyExchange 
                    = repository.findByFromAndTo(from, to);
        
        if(currencyExchange ==null) {
            throw new RuntimeException
                ("Unable to Find data for " + from + " to " + to);
        }
        
        String port = environment.getProperty("local.server.port");
        
        //CHANGE-KUBERNETES
        String host = environment.getProperty("HOSTNAME");
        String version = "v11";
        
        currencyExchange.setEnvironment(port + " " + version + " " + host);
        
        return currencyExchange;
        
    }

}
```

When i do

```sh
kubectl logs -f currency-exchange
```

Attaching below is my log4j.properties file

```properties
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT, file

log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/in28min/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.11-SNAPSHOT/access.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

i can see my logs. But i want my custom logs in a file access.log, so that i can make use of it and do appropriate actions. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing any logs in the `access.log` file from your main container that is why your sidecar can't read any log because the file `/var/log/in28min/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.11-SNAPSHOT/access.log` does not exist. So, cat command of sidecar returns the error. You should write logs from your main container to the file `'/var/log/in28min/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.11- SNAPSHOT/access.log'`

Comment: Hi I am doing that with the help of log4j.properties file. I have done edit to my main question. Please check this.

Comment: Can you exec into the pod and check if `access.log` file exist ?

Comment: no it does not exist. That is what i am worried, why access.log is not getting created. Do i have to create manually?

Comment: Can you try by changing the line `log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/in28min/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.11-SNAPSHOT/access.log` to `log4j.appender.file.File=access.log` ?

Comment: But then how will main-container and side-container detect it? But let me just try as you are saying.

Comment: Hi, It worked with actual configuration. log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/in28min/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.11-SNAPSHOT/access.log. 

I think the issue was i was using an object for slf4j & not log4j. So it was not creating that file. 
But I really appreciate you helping out and giving directions. As due to your suggestions I was able to debug it. Thank you so much.

Your indication was true, access.log was not getting created in main container. And due to this side car container was not able to read it.